# Second order linear differential equation with non-constants coefficients $xy''+2(x+1)y'+((x+2)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I am struggling with this equation on $\mathbb{R}$
$$xy''+2(x+1)y'+(x+2)y=0$$
I was searching for the right substitution but I didn"t find a good way!
Any help, please?

Comment: The solution can not expressed by the known elementary functions.

Comment: The solution is given by $$y(x)=c_1 e^{-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3} x}
   U\left(\frac{1}{2} i \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right),1,i
   \sqrt{3} x\right)+c_2 e^{-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2} i
   \sqrt{3} x} L_{-\frac{1}{2} i
   \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)}\left(i \sqrt{3} x\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank you sir, how could you get that solution please?

Comment: This is the answer given by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thank you

Comment: Generic solution is $y(x)=c_1e^{-x}+c_2\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$ for some constants $c_1, c_2$ (depends on your initial/boundary conditions)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+y%27%27(x)+%2B+2+(x%2B1)+y%27(x)+%2B+(x%2B2)+y(x)+%3D+0) gives a solution as in Sil's comment.

Comment: @Sil this is not defined on $0$ the question was about a solution overall $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @The_lost It's a generic solution. You can choose for example $c_2=0$, if you want it to be defined for $x=0$.

Comment: @Sil Right, it is clear now, how do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By substitut  $z=xy$ on this DE we get
\begin{align}
xy''+2(x+1)y'+(x+2)y&=(xy''+2y')+2(xy'+y)+xy\\
&=z"+2z'+z\\
&=0
\end{align}

now we use the characteristic equation
$$r^2+2r+1=0$$
which has a unique  solution $r=-1$ of multiplicity two, so the solution of this DE is given by

$$z(x)=(ax+b)e^{-x}$$
which mean that the solution of the initial problem on $]-\infty , 0[$ or $]0,\infty[$is  of the form
$$y(x)= \frac{ax+b}{x}e^{-x}$$
Now let $y$  be

$$
y(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{l l}
\frac{a_1x+b_1}{x}e^{-x} & x<0\\
\frac{a_2x+b_2}{x}e^{-x} &x>0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

So $y$ is a solution on $\mathbb{R}^*$, and to be a solution overall $\mathbb{R}$ it is easy to check that $a_1,a_2,b_1;b_2$ must verify
$$ a_1=a_2 \text{ and } b_1=b_2=0$$ 
 Here you are

Answer (score 1):

A particular solution could be $y=e^{ax}$

Then we have that
$$x(a^2+2a+1)+2(a+1)=0$$

$$\implies a=-1 \implies y_p=e^{-x}$$
Now you can use the reduction of order method
$$y=v(x)e^{-x}$$
The equation becomes
$$x(v''-2v')+2(x+1)v'=0$$
$$xv''+2v'=0$$

Which is separable ...
$$(\ln |{v'}|)'=-\frac 2x$$
Integrate twice to get :
$$\implies v(x)=K_1+\frac {K_2}x$$
$$\boxed  {y(x)=e^{-x} \left (K_1+\frac {K_2}x \right)}$$